# Understand crypt()'s output in case of MD5

Tags: c, linux, md5, glibc, crypt

The glibc version of [`crypt(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) function supports MD5 algorithm. According to the documentation:

```
If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
followed by a string optionally terminated by "$", then the result
has the form:

       $id$salt$encrypted
```

The document also states that in case of MD5, `$id` must be 1 and size of the `encrypted` string is fixed to 22 characters.

But MD5 output is always 128-bit length. So how does it come to only 22 characters?

I thought it would be Base64-encoded, since 128 bits can represent 22 Base64 characters. Let's verify my assumption.

Below is simple code I wrote to call `crypt()` with MD5, no salt used for encryption:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char md5[] = "$1$";
    char *res;
    res = crypt("helloworld", md5);
    printf("res = %s\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Run it:

```
$ ./crypt
res = $1$$edK86ZB1Vvaz2eneY.itb.
```

The MD5 encrypted value of `helloworld` according to `crypt()` is `edK86ZB1Vvaz2eneY.itb.`.

Now calculate the MD5 hash of `helloworld` by an [online tool](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php) or by `md5sum`:

```
$ echo -n helloworld | md5sum
fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0  -
```

The MD5 hash value is `fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0`. Convert this hex string to Base64 by [this online converter](http://en.1mu.info/tools/hexbase64.html) or by following command:

```
$ echo "fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0" | xxd -r -p | base64
/F4DjTilcDIIVEHn/nAQsA==
```

This value is different than the value that `crypt()` produced above.

So how does `crypt()` produce its output in this case or how am I supposed to interpret it? What am I missing here?

Comment: "_MD5 encryption algorithm_" NOT encryption!

Comment: The manual page states it uses md5 encryption.

Comment: @curiousguy I think you meant "NOT checksum!"?

Comment: Ok guys. That word is edited out.

Comment: @KamilCuk Then the man is misleading. It's one way hashing.

Answer (score 3):

It uses the MD5 algorithm, but does not return the generated MD5 hash. There are many weird things going on in the source, from [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/crypt/md5-crypt.c#L209):

```
/* The original implementation now does something weird: for every 1
   bit in the key the first 0 is added to the buffer, for every 0
   bit the first character of the key.  This does not seem to be
   what was intended but we have to follow this to be compatible.  */
```

or

```
/* Now comes another weirdness.  In fear of password crackers here
   comes a quite long loop which just processes the output of the
   previous round again.  We cannot ignore this here.  */
```

`__md5_crypt_r` is called from `__crypt_r` from [here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/crypt/crypt-entry.c#L94).

It uses the MD5 algorithm, but it does not return the md5 hash in the user string. Instead it does multiple [transformations](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/crypt/md5-crypt.c#L284) to "encrypt" the input string.

For md5 hashes, use openssl/md5.h. I guess I would advise against using the encryption family functions from libc, unless writing something really small and not portable. From the [html documentation](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_node/libc_651.html):

> [...] the DES uses only a 56-bit key (plus 8 parity bits), and a machine has been built in 1998 which can search through all possible keys in about 6 days, which cost about US$200000; faster searches would be possible with more money. This makes simple DES unsecure for most purposes, and NIST no longer permits new US government systems to use simple DES.

Comment: "It uses md5 algorithm, but does return the generated md5 hash" I think you mean "does not" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo.

Comment: Thanks. So it means that a lot of "weird" transformations is done internally, and without documentation. So sad.

Comment: Also, there's no need to encode the whole MD5 result, as a cryptographic hash has the desired property that a change in just one input bit produces a change in half of the output bits aprox (and in an unpredictable way).... returning only part of it makes it proportionately weaker to the output string length.